# how to configure VirtualBox-5.0 host key and ctrl-c settings?

Tags: fedora, freebsd, virtualbox, keyboard-layout

I'm new to VirtualBox, my platform is Fedora23 (host), VirtualBox-5.0, FreeBSD 10.2 (guest). I really don't know why I cannot use *Ctrl* in VirtualBox guests.

- (1) After switched the "get out of guest" key from right-ctrl to left-alt+right-ctrl. *But Cannot switch it back to right-ctrl.*
- (2) *Cannot use ctrl-c in guest* when I want to stop the runing sh shell. *And Cannot use ctrl-d* to exit the sh shell.

All the problem didn't happen on my windows7 VirtualBox. I wonder how to fix them.
Please help me, I cannot google anything match my problem.

Comment: What do you want exactly to happen,  What happens when you try to do that. If its not working shutdown your virtual machine and try it. it will work.

Comment: I did, restart my Fedora and restart the VirtualBox, not working, still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find something here about the *Ctrl* on VirtualBox guest: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/122

It seems a problem on gnome desktop environment with VirtualBox.

on Fedora23-workstation (gnome3), I set *Caps Lock* as additional *Ctrl* in gnome-tweak-tool. So actually I cannot use *Ctrl-key* in VirtualBox guest is I cannot use *CapsLock-key* in VirtualBox guest.

After I unset the *CapsLock as addtional Ctl*, everything got right.